# Problem displaying images from MySql database PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem while displaying the images from MySQL Database. When I load the page, only the empty image element is loaded but not the actual image coming from database. I think that php code is not correct.

```
<?php 

 //connection do db
require_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';

try{
     $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pictures');
     $stmt->execute();
     if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
     {
         while($row=$stmt->fetchColumn())
         {
             extract($row);
;         }
     } 

}catch (PDOEXception $ex){
    echo $ex;
}
?>
<img src="images/<?php echo $row['path']?>">
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It sounds like the image is not coming from the DB, just the path to the image. If you view source on the, does value of the `img` element's `src` attribute look correct? Is it just `images/` or is there an actual path to an image file there? If it looks correct, then are you sure that is the correct URL to the image on your web server? Could you provide some sample output from the html page and also a full URL to an image that works when requested directly?

Comment: Aren't you missing a `;` after the PHP line? `<?php echo $row['path'];?>`

Comment: `img` tag is outside `while` loop (sidenode: don't post code in lines with ``` - it's not displayed)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create `<img>` tags in while loop. Try:

```
while($row=$stmt->fetchColumn())
{
    extract($row);
    echo '<img src="images/'.$row['path'].'">'; 
}
```